# How to control toolbar location in IE addon (BHO)

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, bho, browser

I'm trying to develop an Internet Explorer 7 addon using "[Browser Helper Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436.aspx)" (BHO). The goal is to have a standard IE toolbar with some buttons and one custom control. I would like to develop it in .NET

I started from the baseline sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx). This works fine but...

- How to control where in the browser the toolbar will show? Currently it just shows on the menu line.
- How to let the user move it like other toolbars. Most other toolbars (built in and addons) have a dashed separator where you can grab and move them.

If there is a better way altogether to develop this (like the FireFox JS addons) I would like to know about it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the baseline toolbar from the link you provided, you may find this  [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Issuewithbandobjects.aspx) useful.  It addresses some of the shortcomings of the toolbar implementation in the original article, including how to move the toolbar (look toward the bottom of the article).

And, as far as I know there isn't a better way to to create a IE add-on in C#/.NET, although I wish there was.